# How to use --environment-variables in az container create via AzureCLI@2 in a CI YAML script

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-cli

Using AzureCLI@2, I'm struggling to figure out how to utilize the `--environment-variables` parameter for `az container create`. Here is what I have tried, with the example environment variable named "SecretDatabase" (scroll to the far right of my command line). Both example fail.

```
az container create --verbose --name $(containerGroupName) --resource-group $(acrResourceGroup) --image $(containerRegistryUrl)/$(imageRepository):$(Build.BuildId) --cpu 1.00 --memory 2.0 --registry-login-server $(containerRegistryUrl) --registry-username "$(containerRegistryName)" --registry-password "$(acrPassword)"  --location eastus --environment-variables SecretDatabase=$env:SecretDatabase

az container create --verbose --name $(containerGroupName) --resource-group $(acrResourceGroup) --image $(containerRegistryUrl)/$(imageRepository):$(Build.BuildId) --cpu 1.00 --memory 2.0 --registry-login-server $(containerRegistryUrl) --registry-username "$(containerRegistryName)" --registry-password "$(acrPassword)"  --location eastus --environment-variables SecretDatabase="$(SecretDatabase)"
```

Comment: What errors did you get when trying with the ways? Share the detailed error logs and the YAML of your pipeline.

Comment: Here is the error:

SecretDatabase : The term 'SecretDatabase' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At /home/vsts/work/_temp/azureclitaskscript1705085686253_inlinescript.ps1:3 char:430
+ …  --environment-variables SecretDatabase="$(SecretDatabase)" …

Answer (score 1):

I have created a test pipeline that uses your `az container create` command, and it has worked for me without issue. Your issue may be down to how you are initializing the `SecretDatabase` variable.

Worth noting that before your `--location` param, you have two spaces. However I tested this on my machine, and the two spaces did not cause any problems.

Here is the example yaml file to create a container using AzureCLI@2:

```
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

variables:
- name: serviceConnection
  value: "redacted"

- name: containerGroupName
  value: "redacted"

- name: acrResourceGroup
  value: "redacted"

- name: containerRegistryImage
  value: "redacted.azurecr.io/redacted:latest"

- name: containerRegistryUrl
  value: "redacted.azurecr.io"

- name: containerRegistryName
  value: "redacted"

- name: acrPassword
  value: "this should be stored in a Key Vault"

- name: SecretDatabase
  value: "Secret Database Name"

steps:

- task: AzureCLI@2
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: ${{ variables.serviceConnection }}
    scriptType: ps
    scriptLocation: inlineScript
    inlineScript: >
        az container create
        --name $(containerGroupName)
        --resource-group $(acrResourceGroup)
        --image $(containerRegistryImage)
        --cpu 1.00
        --memory 2.0
        --registry-login-server $(containerRegistryUrl)
        --registry-username "$(containerRegistryName)"
        --registry-password "$(acrPassword)"
        --location eastus
        --environment-variables SecretDatabase="$(SecretDatabase)"
```

Here is the created container in Azure showing the `SecretDatabase` environment variable:
[click to view screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAWml.png)